# Subclassing a sprite in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

A few days ago, I started working with cocos2d. I really like the framework. I would like to create a game with cocos2d and have a probably simple question...

I am making a game with 4 characters, which all have similar characteristics, but have some different attributes like "type" and "points". I'd like to subclass the sprites into one class which handles all their logic, drawing, and animation.

My question though, is how do I call the sprite class with say, a "type" parameter of 1, 2, 3, or 4 and then have the class draw the correct sprite into my scene with all of it's individual logic?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have an Enemy class that contains properties of specific enemies and that are not type specific (like position, current health, a CCSprite instance?) and an EnemyType class that contains properties that are shared among all enemies of a specific type (max health, max speed, size, sprite filename). You should load your enemy types prior to loading the level, than instantiate each enemy using the appropriate type in the constructor.

For example if your enemy element in the level file looks like this

```
<enemy><type>spider</type>...more properties...</enemy>
```

The code (pseudo) would do something like

```
   EnemyType *enemyType = nil;
   if (typeElement.value == "spider")
   {
       enemyType = spiderType;
   }
   Enemy *newEnemy = [Enemy enemyWithType:enemyType];
```

Also the Enemy class should contain the CCSprite that represents it, not subclass it. An enemy is not a sprite, so unless I'm missing something, as i see it, an enemy should not inherit from a sprite. I'd read about [when to contain and when to inherit](http://www.google.co.il/search?q=when%20to%20inherit%20and%20when%20to%20contain).

**EDIT:**
[Another nice post to read](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/6621) that seems very relevant and could communicate a few other things probably better than me.

Anyway, my intention was not to make you think you should just rethink your entire design. What i'm proposing is "better" MVC-wise, but it doesn't mean it's better for your game. If you spend all your time on "design correctness" you'll never get a game done, especially if you're just learning the cocos2d framework, i was actually making a learning project not too long ago and Steve McConnel himself would come over and slap me if he saw it.

If you're working on a game alone and it's a small project go ahead and subclass away if it's going to be more manageable to you, everything, including "design correctness" needs to be properly quantified (except maybe usage of "goto" statements :) ).

Comment: sure, make your answer better than mine. I can only assume that @Nick is going to have some learning to do, and hopefully wont get discouraged if his first attempt isn't as clean and easy to expand on as he had hoped.

Comment: @Grady Player i was just proposing something different, cleanliness should not be the top concern when building a learning project. However this WAS a design question so i felt i had to answer it and point out a certain thing i considered to be a design flaw, anyway, i edited my answer, and the last thing i want is to discourage anyone :)

Comment: @Grady Player also the cocos2d paradigm of adding objects to a scene DOES very much seem to beg for you to subclass objects and just add them enemies and turrets to the scene, so as i mentioned in the original answer, if this IS a conventional way of doing things in cocos, someone please put me in my place

Comment: I always just subclass sprite, if you don't you may have to end up subclassing it anyway so as to hold a reference to the the controlling object.

Answer (score 0):

polymorphism in this way can be done a couple of different ways, some better than others.
1) you could try to just override the init or node method and set up your object there.

```
+(CCSprite *)node
{
    MySprite * returnSprite = [super node];
    returnSprite.hat = @"fedora";
    returnSprite.hatImage = [CCSprite spriteWithImage:...];

}
```

2) use reflection (psuedocode)

```
-(void)drawingMethodHere
{
     [self.hat drawAtPoint:somePoint];
}
```

then override `-(CCNode *)hat` to reflect the type.

you may have to do some combination of them, but plan a little before you start, you will end up saving a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

You should subclass CCNode instead of subclassing CCSprite.

I think your problem is quite easy. Just create a base class called Character, which has the common logic, properties etc etc. Then you create 4 other classes like, enemy, player and so on and subclass from Character base. Note the character base should be subclassing CCNode.

Now you override the logic to fit your needs in the specific class. Now you will be able to use polymorphism, which is good.

For your sprite I would say create an instance variable of the CCSprite type and then create methods to initialize with an image. Then you will just add that sprite as a child when initializing the object.